# How would I match column values to row values in another dataframe with multiple values per row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say I have:

df1

```
index  name
0      bobby   
1      alex
2      timmy
3      dale
4      chadwick
5      dillon
6      jade
```

and  df2:

```
index  vote1     vote2     vote3
0        2         3         1
1        1         4         3   
2        1         4         2
3        4         3         Nan
4        2         0         6
```

and I want to figure out who is the most popular by matching their index values from df2 to their index called in the rows and summing them.

I have gotten stuck at this point.

My expected output is

```
Name         Votes
Chadwick      3
dale          3
alex          3
timmy         3
boby          1
jade          1
dillon        0
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Kindly include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df2 = df2.replace('Nan', np.nan).astype(str)
df1.index = df1.index.astype(str)
df2.stack().map(df1['name']).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
timmy       3
dale        3
chadwick    3
alex        3
bobby       1
jade        1
dtype: int64
```

Use `stack` then make sure the dtypes of df1 and df2 match, use `map` and `value_counts`.

Answer (score 3):

1. You could `replace` the numeric df2 values with their name equivalents from df1
2. Then, `melt` the dataframe to make it go in one column
3. Get the value counts of that column
4. Send it to a dataframe and do some cleanup

---

```
df2.replace(df1['name']).melt().iloc[:,-1].value_counts()
Out[1]: 
dale        3
alex        3
chadwick    3
timmy       3
jade        1
bobby       1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

If all of your data is not `float` or `int`, then you can use:

```
df2 = (df2.replace('Nan', np.nan).astype(float) #You had a 'Nan' string in your question, so you can remove ".replace('Nan', np.nan)"
          .replace(df1['name']).melt().iloc[:,-1].value_counts())
```

To make this a dataframe, you can do:

```
df2 = (df2.replace(df1['name'])
           .melt(value_name='Votes')
           .iloc[:,-1]
           .value_counts()
           .to_frame()
           .reset_index()
           .rename({'index' : 'Name'}, axis=1))
df2
Out[3]: 
       Name  Votes
0      dale      3
1      alex      3
2  chadwick      3
3     timmy      3
4     bobby      1
5      jade      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m = df1.name.to_dict()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.name.values)
df2.replace("Nan", -1).astype(int)
for col in df2.columns:
    df3[col] = df2[col].map(d).value_counts()

df3 = df3.sum(axis=1)
```